# PHP, random image code generation integrated with CSS

Tags: php, html, css, image, random

I had a piece of code which randomly selected an image for display on a website. That however was before I upgraded my HTML skills with CSS. Now I want to integrate the CSS into the PHP code.

I never was good with PHP, and only managed the random image generator because a friend did the coding for me. Now I have no idea how to integrate the required formatting characters from the CSS into the PHP.

Original Code:

```
<?php 
$images = array("banner001.jpg", "banner002.jpg", "banner003.jpg", 
"banner004.jpg", "banner005.jpg", "banner006.jpg", "banner007.jpg", "banner008.jpg", 
"banner009.jpg", "banner010.jpg", "banner011.jpg", "banner012.jpg", "banner013.jpg", 
"banner014.jpg", "banner015.jpg",); mt_srand((double)microtime() * 1000000); 
$num = array_rand($images); 
print("<img src=\"_pic-lib/banner-bg/".$images[$num]."\" alt=\"A random banner image\" class=\"bordered\" id=\"rightside\" />");
?>
```

Working HTML w/ CSS that does a single image:

```
<table id="banner"><tr><td id="banner" style="background-image:url('_pic-lib/banner-
bg/banner005.jpg')"><img src="_pic-lib/banner.png" alt="NCPAM GRS Banner" /></td>    
</tr></table>
```

Hybrid code I have so far: (which doesn't work)

```
<table id="banner"><tr><?php $images = array("banner001.jpg", "banner002.jpg",
"banner003.jpg", "banner004.jpg", "banner005.jpg", "banner006.jpg", "banner007.jpg",
"banner008.jpg", "banner009.jpg", "banner010.jpg", "banner011.jpg", "banner012.jpg", 
"banner013.jpg", "banner014.jpg", "banner015.jpg",); mt_srand((double)microtime() * 
1000000); $num = array_rand($images); print("<td id=\"banner\" style=\"background-
image:url('_pic-lib/banner-bg/".$images[$num]. '\")" alt=\"A random banner image\" 
/>");?></td></tr></table>
```

[Website where code is to be used.](http://ncpam.fccorp.us/index.php)

The picture on top is what the final result is supposed to be. The second picture is the randomly selected picture code, without the CSS integrated. The third image... which isn't there... is the final integrated version.

@

Comment: please re-format your code so that we can read all of them (I did one for you)

Comment: So what are you trying to do? are you trying to include images via CSS? I don't get the problem clearly

Comment: Jereme - I need the images selected by the PHP code to be CSS compliant. Its a simple context issue, I don't know how to "translate" the css formatting into coding which is something the php can parse.

Answer (score 0):

Actually figured it out. Turns out that the "View Page Source" in firefox is a decent code debugger. It has syntax highlighting which can be very helpful in diagnosing code errors.

```
<table id="banner2"><tr><?php $images = array("banner001.jpg", "banner002.jpg",
"banner003.jpg", "banner004.jpg", "banner005.jpg", "banner006.jpg", "banner007.jpg",
"banner008.jpg", "banner009.jpg", "banner010.jpg", "banner011.jpg", "banner012.jpg",
"banner013.jpg", "banner014.jpg", "banner015.jpg",); mt_srand((double)microtime() * 
1000000); $num = array_rand($images); print("<td id=\"banner2\" style=\"background-
image:url('_pic-lib/banner-bg/$images[$num]')\" >");?><img src="_pic-lib/banner.png"
alt="NCPAM GRS Banner" /></td></tr></table>
```